# Mongoose count returning wrong data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Meeting.count(countQuery).then(countBookings)
.then(findUser)
. // a few more then blocks, that are not relevant to my problem
.
.
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('The meeting error is ', err);
})
```

This is my count query object:

```
let countQuery = {
 startDate: {$gte: date1, $lte: date2},
 teamId: req.body.teamId
};
```

This is my count booking function:

```
const countBookings = (data) => {
console.log('reached countBookings')
if (data >= 6 || data + bookingDet.length > 6) {
  res.status(403).json({message: 'Can\'t book for more than 3 hours in a day'})
  throw new Error('More than 3 bookings in a day are not allowed.')
} else {
  return true
}
}
```

Here's the situation that I am facing. I need to prevent a user from booking for more than 6 slots. For testing purposes, I first booked 2 slots, and then I was able to book 6 slots. And when i tried to book again, this time it worked.

I tried `console.log()` and repeated the same step, and turns out mongoose is not counting the first bookings. But when I tried the third time, i received 6 bookings from the `count` query. When I tested through mongoshell, and after first booking of 2 slots, it returned me the correct count.

I event tried `find()` but the issue is the same? Why is it happening?